# Windows phone 8 - Page Navigation (Skipping Pages)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

> In windows 8 phone, while I navigate from page1 to page 2 and then to page 3 and when returning back from page 3 I have to skip page 2

Answer (score 0):

Use NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry(). This removes the last entry in the navigation stack. You can do this directly after navigating to page 3 in the OnNavigatedTo method.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    ...
}
```